# Appending multiple SQLite DB files into one single giant file

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, merge, append

I have multiple ***SQLite .db*** files. Each DB file has the same schema having multiple tables but different values in them. I want to merge the DB files in such a way that if a duplicate row exists in other database files, it is discarded otherwise appended in a master DB file that would contain values from all the files.

Preferably, I would like to automate the process.

Comment: `ATTACH DATABASE` and `INSERT OR IGNORE ... SELECT ...` are your friends.

Comment: @Shawn can you point out some tutorial or blog post etc revolving around above-mentioned commands to achieve am looking for?

Comment: The documentation isn't enough? https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: No. For someone like who is a beginner, it's rather daunting and difficult to understand